# Converting a windows path to a path using environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables

Is there a Python library that takes a windows path and replaces expanded environment variables with environment variables?

**For example:**

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents\Text.txt -> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Text.txt
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -> %WINDIR%\System32\cmd.exe
C:\Program Files\Program\Program.exe -> %PROGRAMFILES%\Program\Program.exe
```

The best way to explain would be to get functionality that does the opposite of

```
os.path.expandvars('some path with environment variables')
```

Support for different languages would also be a requirement.

```
C:\Archivos de programa\Progra\Program.exe -> %PROGRAMFILES%\Program\Program.exe
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible, or at least it is ambiguous. There is nothing to say that there is a one-to-one mapping of directories to environment variables. In other words I could have both `%FOO%` and `%BAR%` that both expand to `C:\Windows`, in that case which should I use?

Comment: There is a [`winshell`](https://winshell.readthedocs.io/) module, specifically its [Special Folders](https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/special-folders.html) part that grabs some of the special folders. For the rest you'll have to use Win32 API. Then it's just a matter of checking if your path intersects with the special folder and replacing it with its canonical _environment variable_ name - you can use the `os.path` facilities for that.

Comment: @CoryKramer it only needs to map to known default windows environment variables, not any new ones.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial problem since more than environment variables may match parts of your string (ex: `PROCESSOR_LEVEL` is usually a single digit, so you should avoid it). To ensure the best efficiency, I would:

- sort the existing environment variable l

like this:

```
import os

my_string = os.path.normpath(r"D:\Users\JOTD\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player")


for k,v in sorted(os.environ.items(),key=lambda x:len(x[1]),reverse=True):
    my_new_string = my_string.replace(v+os.sep,"%{}%{}".format(k,os.sep))
    if my_string != my_new_string:
        break
    my_string = my_new_string

print(my_new_string)
```